# Android program

Tags: android

I have created an android application but it is not running properly. I don't know why it always stops at this line in the console.

```
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Starting activity com.example.Android.AndroidBitmapActivity on device emulator-5554
```

My program is as follows, which is code for the rotation of a bitmap
    package com.example.Android;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AndroidBitmapActivity extends Activity {

    private final String imageInSD = "/sdcard/er.PNG";

    ImageView myImageView;
    Spinner spinnerScale;
    SeekBar seekbarRotate;

    private static final String[] strScale 
        = {"0.2x", "0.5x", "1.0x", "2.0x", "5.0x"}; 
    private static final Float[] floatScale 
        = {0.2F, 0.5F, 1F, 2F, 5F};
    private final int defaultSpinnerScaleSelection = 2;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterScale;

    private float curScale = 1F;
    private float curRotate = 0F;

    Bitmap bitmap;
    int bmpWidth, bmpHeight;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        spinnerScale = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.scale);
        seekbarRotate = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.rotate);

        adapterScale = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strScale);
        adapterScale.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerScale.setAdapter(adapterScale);
        spinnerScale.setSelection(defaultSpinnerScaleSelection);
        curScale = floatScale[defaultSpinnerScaleSelection];

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
        bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        drawMatrix();

        spinnerScale.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerScaleOnItemSelectedListener);
        seekbarRotate.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekbarRotateSeekBarChangeListener);

    }

    private void drawMatrix(){

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
        matrix.postRotate(curRotate);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

    }

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekbarRotateSeekBarChangeListener
        = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                curRotate = (float)progress;
                drawMatrix();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};

    private Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener spinnerScaleOnItemSelectedListener
        = new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                curScale = floatScale[arg2];
                drawMatrix();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinnerScale.setSelection(defaultSpinnerScaleSelection);
                curScale = floatScale[defaultSpinnerScaleSelection];
            }};
}
```

my manifest file is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidBitmapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my console is showing following thing

```
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Android Launch!
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Performing com.example.Android.AndroidBitmapActivity activity launch
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'A2.2'
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Uploading AndroidBitmap.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Installing AndroidBitmap.apk...
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Success!
[2012-03-29 13:23:00 - AndroidBitmap] Starting activity com.example.Android.AndroidBitmapActivity on device emulator-5554
```

Answer (score 2):

At a guess I would say you haven't declared the AndroidBitmapActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file, but I think it would be helpful if you posted more of the stacktrace (and possibly the Manifest file too).

Comment: Hmmm. Ok it seems to not be the manifest then. Could you post the entire stack trace so I have a line reference and specific exception to help you with?

Comment: you means stack trace on the console.

Comment: Is there any more output? There's no force close in that log

Comment: there is no force to close it is not opening the activity only

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry, I didn't notice you edited the comment that said "it is closing the application forcely". Has the emulator loaded and the OS is running?

Comment: but why program is not running

Comment: That's what I'm trying to help you with. But you'll need to provide more information, like answering the questions I asked. Is the emulator actually running? If so, has the OS completely finished loading?

Comment: yes emulator is running but it stop on that line which is mention in the above .

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the SD Card?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You will need permissions in Manifest if you are trying to access the SDCard...    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);

Answer (score 0):

it should have a problem with your SD card (if not created then create it first )and  i think you haven't a image "er.PNG" in your SD card(if same name image is not in your sd card it will never run)  first check out it properly and let try...